# Periodically cut and paste files

Tags: cron, paste, cut-command

I'm running a model that generates quite a stream of outputs. In fact they are so many that it ends up dying because the hard-drive is filled up

Is there a way (maybe with cron) to periodically scan a folder and cut and paste data on different storages (i have many secondary drives)? The method should have a way to check for file-size before proceeding or, better still, check if there's activity on the file to avoid moving incomplete files that the model is still writing.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jacob, I should not need to swap hard drives

Comment: Well, I know which is the final filesize...it's true that I do not know when it's reached, but the model writes in discrete time steps so I guess that if the file it's already that big it's done. Also since the filename is timestamped I could probably add a check if the next file is in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know the exact details of your setup you may have to modify this but with a [find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) and a [mv](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html#mv-invocation) command:

```
find /path/to/output -type f -size -1M -name 'modeloutput*' -exec mv -t /data/secondarydrive/ {} \+
```

You could add this as a [Cronjob](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

It will move all files in the /path/to/output dircetory with that filename starts with 'modeloutput' and are bigger than 1 Magebyte to the /data/secondarydrive directory.

Comment: Can you explain the \+ at the end ?     Also it might be prudent to check for available space in the target directory prior to exec'ing the mv.

Comment: ... perhaps using a test on 'df -kP /data/secondarydrive/' |  awk '/[0-9]%/{print $(NF-2)}' being more than a predetermined available space, say 1000000  blocks.  @Mutewinter: in this case blocks are 1024 bytes (-k option in df so that 10⁶ blocks are 1GB).

Comment: The + means it will append the files found to the mv command rather then calling mv multiple times.

Comment: Yup. That's clear. But why to you escape it ?